# Next.js - dynamic import vs await import

Tags: next.js, dynamic-import

I'm wondering about the difference between `dynamic import` (next.js feature) and `await import`.
I couldn't find an explanation about the difference online.
I know that you can use `dynamic import` only to import `React Components` and not libraries.
But why should I use `dynamic import` and not just `await import` ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As they explain here https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import, you should use `next/dynamic` when you import dynamic React components to be sure that NextJS is able to match webpack bundles to a specific dynamic call, and preload the component before rendering it.

So the answer to you question is yes, you should use Nextjs `dynamic` import, and not `await import` (btw, `await import` is just a way to load `ES2020 dynamic imports` )